# length mismatch in folium?

Tags: python, pandas, folium, choropleth

I'm working on coding a folium map and I keep getting this error. I'm new to this and honestly have no idea how to fix this.

```
import folium

geojson_map = 'https://raw.gituserhubcontent.com/dirkkoolmees/maps-import-export-of-fossil-fuels-/master/custom.geo.json'

world_map = folium.Map(location=[0,0], zoom_start = 1.5, tiles = 'CartoDB positron', min_zoom = 1, max_zoom = 6)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = geojson_map,
    name = "chloropleth",
    data = df_clean,
    columns = [df.index, 'value'],
    key_on= 'feature.properties.name_sort',
    fill_color = 'Reds',
    fill_opacity = 0.9,
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    legend_name = 'GDP'
    ).add_to(world_map)

world_map
```

this is the error I receive:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-b88f980d229d> in <module>()
     13     fill_color = 'Reds',
     14     fill_opacity = 0.9,
---> 15     line_opacity = 0.2,
     16     #legend_name = 'GDP'
     17     ).add_to(world_map)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   4597                 # ensure_index_from_sequences would not raise for append=False.
   4598                 raise ValueError(
-> 4599                     f"Length mismatch: Expected {len(self)} rows, "
   4600                     f"received array of length {len(arrays[-1])}"
   4601                 )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 154 rows, received array of length 324
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Break out the two calls into two lines

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not positive what exactly you mean by that. Could you show me how It would be properly formatted? Thanks

Comment: Separate `folium.Choropleth(...).add_to(world_map)` into `c = folium.Choropleth(...); c.add_to(world_map)`

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Comment: It's not the same error because now it tells you which part actually causes the error

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - and what are sizes of data. ie `len(geojson_map)`, `len(df_clean)` - probably one of them has size 154 and other 324 and this can makes problem. OR maybe problem makes `df.index` ?

Comment: @furas It seems the geojson_map has a length of 105 while the data frame has a length of 154. Would I need to shorten my dataframe to work?

Answer (score 0):

- there are a few errors in your code

  1. URL to GitHub is wrong
  2. neither `df_clean` or `df` are defined
- fixing these, the code works, noting there are 175 geometries in your GeoJSON
- it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but this code then works.  Not sure why you are using `df` and `df_clean` that can have different numbers of rows

```
import folium
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

geojson_map = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkkoolmees/maps-import-export-of-fossil-fuels-/master/custom.geo.json'

world_map = folium.Map(location=[0,0], zoom_start = 1.5, tiles = 'CartoDB positron', min_zoom = 1, max_zoom = 6)

# code is using two different dataframes! create them...
df_clean = pd.DataFrame(index=range(175), data={"value":np.linspace(1,5,175)})
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(175))

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = geojson_map,
    name = "chloropleth",
    data = df_clean,
    columns = [df.index, 'value'],
    key_on= 'feature.properties.name_sort',
    fill_color = 'Reds',
    fill_opacity = 0.9,
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    legend_name = 'GDP'
    ).add_to(world_map)

world_map
```